# How does this linq code that splits a sequence work?

Tags: c#, linq

I've been staring at this code which I found in another question (copied verbatim below) and I know it's not much, but it's escaping me how the i++ % parts works.

```
void Main()
{
    int[] a = new [] { 10, 3, 5, 22, 223 };

    a.Split(3).Dump();

}
static class LinqExtensions 
{ 
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int parts) 
    { 
        int i = 0; 
        var splits = from item in list 
                     group item by i++ % parts into part 
                     select part.AsEnumerable(); 
        return splits; 
    } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It groups the items into the number of parts that you specify. The i++ will increment for each item and apply the modulus operator so that it puts it in the correct number of buckets. So the first item goes in bucket 0, 2nd in bucket 1, 3rd in bucket 2, 4th in bucket 0, etc...

Answer (score 6):

While [Keith Rousseau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10238653/45914) is correct, I would argue that the idea is a rather bad way to achieve this. You can achieve it more purely (i.e., without having to mutate a captured variable) via:

```
var splits = list.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
                 .GroupBy(pair => pair.Index % parts, element => element.Item)
                 .Select(group => group.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: Every time I think I'm good a LINQ, someone like you shows up :) +1 sir.

Comment: It is debatable which way is “better”. Yours is definitely purer (more functional). The `i++` way is definitely much faster (much fewer heap allocations). Which one is preferred must be evaluated in the context of whatever the ultimate goal is.

Comment: `IGrouping` already implements `IEnumerable`, you could probably get away with a cast in the last select, or if it's C# 4, rely on interface covariance.

Comment: @Timwi: "Much" is a stretch. It's only `O(n)` additional heap allocations.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, it’s `O(n)`, and that is a heck of a lot more than `O(1)` :)